# Change text in multiple TextViews with same Tag/ID

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with trying set multiple text views with the same text when it changes. I have multiple `TextViews` that need to be set with the same values. What I've been doing is just using each ID and setting the value of each independently but this doesn't seem very efficient. Basically what I'm doing is:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_1_1)).setText("text 1");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_1_2)).setText("text 1");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_2_1)).setText("text 2");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_2_2)).setText("text 2");
.....
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_5_1)).setText("text 5");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_5_2)).setText("text 5");
```

I'd prefer not to store each TextView as a global variable in my class because there are so many. Is there a preferred approach to this or a simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: For that number of views (10), short of aggrouping in the most convenient methods I do not think anything would be worth the effort. If there are many more maybe you could use reflection.

Comment: Do you try to use ListView or same view?

Comment: Any time you have a large number of Views like that you should be wondering to yourself if you could better achieve what you are aiming for with some sort of AdapterView (i.e. ListView, GridView etc). Almost always the answer will be yes. Without more context on what you are trying to achieve though I can't really point you in a more specific direction. At the very least you should be keeping references to your TextViews. `findViewById()` is a relatively expensive method to call. Calling it everytime you need to change text will degrade performance.

Comment: It looks like your TextViews are organized in a way that resembles a 2d array. You could create a global 2d array (or ArrayList<String[]>) to represent all of your text views. This isn't more efficient than what you have, but it would look and feel cleaner.

Comment: @FoamyGuy: Thanks for the suggestions. I guess I wasn't very clear on my current setup above. I have a couple of sections of layouts that are hidden or visible based on the current state of the app. Some of these sections have the same information, same text but different stylings. I was hoping there would be a better way then just iterating through each TextView to set the value. I'm not sure an Adapter would work because they are located in different layouts.

I do have more than 10 views too so I'm not sure what the limit would be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your Views using tags: Just use the same tag (for example **group1**)for the textviews that are of the same group. Then call `fix(yourRootView, "group1", "the_new_value");`

```
    protected void fix(View child, String thetag, String value) {
        if (child == null)
            return;

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            fix((ViewGroup) child, thetag, value);
        }
        else if (child instanceof TextView) {
            doFix((TextView) child, thetag, value);
        }
    }

    private void fix(ViewGroup parent, String thetag, String value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            fix(parent.getChildAt(i), thetag, value);
        }
    }
    private void doFix(TextView child, String thetag, String value) {
        if(child.getTag()!=null && child.getTag().getClass() == String.class) {
            String tag= (String) child.getTag();
            if(tag.equals(thetag)) {
                child.setText(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I had tried something similar but wasn't able to get it quite right.